Fourier transform and Welch power spectral density
Consider a signal $x(t)$ that I compare to the Lora waveform. The bandwidth is $B=125$ kHz.


In the previous figures 'new waveform' corresponds to the signal $x(t)$. Here are my questions:

On the power spectral density figure, I would like to know why the bandwidth seems larger than the Lora one when in theory the bandwidths are identical. Also, what are the disadvantages of having a signal $x(t)$ with a power spectral density like in the figure?

For the Fourier transform, it's a bit the same as for the power spectral density but here the bandwidth of the signal $x(t)$ seems smaller. And I would also like to know the disadvantage of having a smaller bandwidth while theoretically the bandwidths are the same.



Your signal seems to be very “peaky”. Welch’s has this effect for tone-like signals, for example see https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/93775/why-is-the-sample-spectrum-considered-inconsistent/93782#93782

My signal is not a tone. The bandwidth is $125$ kHz.

How exactly do you define "bandwidth"? Your "new waveform"   doesn't look like it has a bandwidth of 125 kHz

Are you doing amplitude tapering on the waveform? Your waveform is nearly zero by the time it gets to 100 kHz bandwidth. Regardless, Welch's is still biased, and so will not always give you an accurate PSD.

To find the bandwidth I use the instantaneous frequency of the signal $x(t)$. And then I use the same construction as for the Lora with: $mod(f_x(t),B)-B/2$ where $f_x$ is the instantaneous frequency of $x(t)$ and $mod$ the modulo operation. Then I integrate with respect to time and use the exponential. Which gives: $\phi(t)=\int (mod(f_x(t),B)-B/2)dt$ and $x(t)=e^{j2 \pi \phi(t)}$

Let us express the signal as
$$
x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \alpha_n \phi_n(t),
$$
where each function $\phi_n$ is chosen to be orthonormal and to have the property that its effective bandwidth matches $B$. For instance, one might let ${\phi_n}$ be a set of orthonormal Hermite functions, well known for minimizing the product of temporal and spectral spreads. In theory, each $\phi_n$ has most of its energy contained within $\pm \tfrac{B}{2}$ in frequency, but the superposition of infinitely many such functions can have sidelobes that extend the apparent bandwidth beyond $\pm \tfrac{B}{2}$. The Welch power spectral density estimate further applies a window $w(t)$ and slices the data, so the effective frequency-domain representation becomes
$$
\widehat{X}(\omega) = \mathcal{F}{w(t) \cdot x(t)},
$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform. Even if $\text{supp}{\phi_n}$ (the main support of each basis function) remains within $\pm \tfrac{B}{2}$, the multiplication by $w(t)$ can create a convolution-like effect in frequency, causing the observed PSD to spill over a region broader than $\pm \tfrac{B}{2}$. The disadvantage of this broader spill is that it increases out-of-band emission and possible interference with adjacent channels.
In contrast, when examining the raw Fourier transform
$$
X(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) e^{-j \omega t} , dt,
$$
it might appear narrower because the main spectral lobe is concentrated, but the amplitude in the tails might be suppressed below the typical observation threshold. Having a smaller visible main-lobe bandwidth can reduce diversity in frequency resources and limit the resiliency of the modulation to channel impairments; one loses the robustness that a fully spread signal might offer against fading. Thus, while the theoretical support of $x(t)$ is still $\pm \tfrac{B}{2}$, details of windowing, superposition, and the method used to estimate power spectra can make the bandwidth look artificially broader or narrower in plots, and each situation carries trade-offs between interference, compliance with allocated spectrum, and robustness to channel effects.
